# Is there a way to retrieve Metabase Questions Table JSON output via API?

Tags: metabase

The Metabase (https://metabase.com/) Data Explorer web UI has the ability to create queries they call questions with various filters. The query results can be visualized in a variety of ways including a table and charts. The table results can also be downloaded as JSON. Is there a way to retrieve the JSON via the Metabase REST API?

I've tried a few of the endpoints in the Metabase API Reference with the ID in the URL of the Data Explorer without success.

API Reference: [https://github.com/metabase/.../api-documentation.md](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/docs/api-documentation.md)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using the following endpoint where `:card-id` is the numeric "`questionId`" in the Data Explorer URL after `/question/`.

[POST /api/card/:card-id/query/:export-format](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/docs/api-documentation.md#post-apicardcard-idqueryexport-format)

As an example:

- Web URL: `https://metabase.example.com/question/1`
- API URL: `https://metabase.example.com/api/card/1/query/json`